# Add delete function in my project

Tags: android, file-management

I use this code for my contextual menu and I make a simple commands. But how to integrate real commands in this?

I want make real function.

```
@Override  
       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Optiuni");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copiaza");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Sterge");

    }  

     @Override  
     public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
             if(item.getTitle()=="Copiaza"){copyFunction(item.getItemId());}  
         else if(item.getTitle()=="Sterge"){deleteFunction(item.getItemId());}
         else {return false;}  
     return true;  
     }  

     public void deleteFunction(int id){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
     public void copyFunction(int id){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copiat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
```

Comment: What you want to copy or delete?

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code ?

Comment: I want delete selected files but i don't no how implement commands. Sorry for my bad language.

Comment: @RaulPetrescu : where is your delete file commands plz also edit delete commands code with question

Comment: you still didnt implement any logic to delete or edit the file.. So instead of showing a toast you need to write the logic for deleting the particular file

Comment: There is the problem i don't now how write the logic. I have som example here but i don't now ho to do it. http://pastebin.com/9Nzc9FAN

Comment: Are you getting the file names from your sdcard? 
If so how are you displaying them

Comment: There is the main activity. http://pastebin.com/YaQ35Lt8

Comment: @G_S Like e normal ListView/ LinearLayout

Comment: I think you can get the file path when you click on the particular list item.. Using that you can call the delete() that you mentioned.. Tried it?

Comment: I i'm not to good at java i'm very newby and i dont no how do it :(. @G_S

Comment: File file = new File(path);
boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
These lines help you in deleting the particular file.
Just pass the path of the file that you are selecting as the parameter 'path'

Comment: Sorty but i understand can u provide me entire code...

Comment: It's not good to compare manu titles instead of ids. Also you should apply different ids to different menu items.

Comment: @G_S I can add this to my logic deleteFunction.

Comment: Yes you can add that to the deletefunction and check if the file gets deleted or not. The reason for i am not able to provide u with the working code is i havent configured eclipse.. sorry for this... So once try what that does and be back if u have any issues still